# Which lifecycle event is best to register/unregister listeners?

Tags: android, android-activity, listener, lifecycle

I have manager classes that take an activity as a listener. I use the managers to do threaded calls, work etc and then call back to the listener(activity) when things are done, need changed and so on.

I want to register and unregister the activity as a listener when it is no longer visible. This will prevent unwanted changes from happening (like dialogs appearing when the activity is no longer visible).

My question is, what lifecycle events are best to do this registering. I started with onPause() and onResume() which worked well except when I had an activity that was doing stuff in onActivityResult(). Since onActivityResult() gets called before onResume() my managers are not always registered in time.

Do I need to register in onResume() AND onActivityResult() or is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: If the listener is needed for the entire lifecycle of the Activity then use onCreate and onDestroy

Comment: This won't work for me, lets say I send off a network thread and the user navigates forward in an activity stack. The activity is still registered(onDestroy() would not have been called). If the call comes back and I decide to popup a dialog box there will be a crash because the activity is not visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative approach may be to postpone the processing currently done in onActivityResult() until after the listeners are registered in onResume().

Possible ways of doing this include posting to the message queue, e.g. using a Handler, setting a Runnable object to be called by onResume, or simply storing the result data received by onActivityResult().

This would also ensure that the activity really has come to the foreground when the listener methods are called.

Comment: So far this is probably the best or most proper way to do it. I'm not sure I will actually go with this, because it is just easier to register my listeners in onActivityResult as well, kinda a hack.

Answer (score 2):

onResume() and onPause() are the best for this.  The onDestroy(), per the documentation, is not guaranteed to be invoked though this is a favorite for many people, so stick with the pauses and resumes.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I agree, but what about my onActivityResult issue?

Comment: Store your "results" in a queue (FIFO), and when the Activity registers go ahead and send over the data, which can then be processed anyway you need/want.  Keep sending the data until the Activity unregisters via the onPause(), at which point begin to store values in the queue again.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the handle of the current Activity in the Manager class. Register its presence on `onCreate()` and unregister it on either `onCreate()` by some other Activity, or `onBackPressed()` of the current Activity.

On a related note, I would recommend an MVC (or similar) architecture where the controller has awareness of the view's status (the controller can track the `onCreate()` and `onBackPressed()` of each Activity).

Comment: Not all of these managers are singletons, ie they cannot and should not be referenced by other activities. They way I approach this is that the activity is really the view controller, the manager just helps it with some more of the complex logic a view controller should not need to do.

Comment: What I meant is that, can you not have a singleton (for simplicity sake) Controller, which in turn could talk to the various managers, on a need basis?